Tornado cash router verified smart contract in sepolia or other testnet network?
I'm trying to understand the inner workings of the Tornado Cash smart contract and how it's implemented specifically in Sepolia or another testnet network. I’ve read some basics about Tornado Cash being a privacy tool that allows users to mix their ETH, but I want to dive deeper into how the smart contract operates and interacts with it.

Probably easiest to deploy it locally. and analyze I think it doesn't have external dependencies, so it should be rather easy to deploy.
